# Set request body in httputil reverse proxy

Tags: http, go, reverse-proxy, go-gin

I am doing a reverse proxy thing which just forwards your request on another server but I am unable to set the body.

```golang
// post request from endpoint /forwarder.
// Called this using Router.post('/forwarder', ReverseProxy()) 
func ReverseProxy() gin.HandlerFunc {

    endpoint := "http://localhost:3001"
    remote, _ := url.Parse(endpoint)
    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(remote)
    
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
            body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
            body_string := string(body)
            fmt.Printf("this is data from rqeuest\n%v\n", c.Request.Body)
            //Define the director func
            proxy.Director = func(req *http.Request) {
                req.Header = c.Request.Header
                req.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(strings.NewReader(body_string))
                req.ContentLength = int64(len(body_string))
                
                fmt.Printf("this is data different \n%v\n", req.Body)
                temp, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)
                fmt.Printf("this is data from req.body\n%v\n", string(temp))
                
                req.Host = remote.Host
                req.URL.Scheme = remote.Scheme
                req.URL.Host = remote.Host
                req.URL.Path = c.Param("proxyPath")
                
            }
      proxy.ServeHTTP(c.Writer, c.Request)
    }
}
```

This results in

```
 http: proxy error: http: ContentLength=43 with Body length 0
```

Removing the `req.ContentLength = int64(len(body_string))` forwards the request to the server running at `localhost:3001` but the body is `undefined`.

How do I set the body?

Comment: Could be that the body reader's internal cursor is at the end of the file, which would cause it to return `io.EOF` immediately upon subsequent read attempts.

Comment: How do I fix it? Just started working with go.

Comment: First try if it's really the issue, remove the line `temp, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)` (and the one after which depends on `temp`) and see if then your director works.

Comment: Actually you might wanna remove both `io.ReadAll` calls if you don't need them. Or do you need them? What for?

Comment: Second one I can remove, it was just for debugging. First one I am using for reassignment. I can remove this as well but how do I assign the old request body to the new one?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about gin but when using the proxy with http.ServeMux you don't need to set the body, the body is already set, you only need to modify stuff needed for the proxy to know where to send the request, like the host.

Comment: Yeah you don't need to set the body with gin as well, I can confirm. I hadn't use a middleware with express-node server that I created. Adding the line `app.use(express.json())` fixed it. Thanks for the help!!